# Overwrite file when copying into zip file using Microsoft Shell COM Library

Tags: excel, vba, shell, com, scripting

I'm using Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation COM library from VBA.  I have a zip file and I am copying a file into the zip file.  The problem is that the file already exists and it throws a dialog box which says "There is already a file with the same name in this location do you want to a) Copy And Replace or b) Don't copy".  I would like to programmatically say Copy And Replace (overwrite!).

I think the equivalent on the .NET  framework has a documentation page at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms723207%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
but I have tried a variety of these.

Also, I will accept removing the original item so that the addition succeeds with no problem; sadly I could not find a delete item method.

I am using Windows 8, 64 bit edition.  I'm in Excel (14) VBA (7) and the library I'm using is at C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll

Here is head of IDL of the type library I'm talking about

```
   // Generated .IDL file (by the OLE/COM Object Viewer)
   // 
   // typelib filename: shell32.dll

   [
      uuid(50A7E9B0-70EF-11D1-B75A-00A0C90564FE),
      version(1.0),
      helpstring("Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation")
   ]
   library Shell32
   {
       // TLib :     // TLib : OLE Automation : {00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
```

Comment: yes, you can delete the file **as long as you have the privileges to do that**. In VBA you know you can disable pop-ups which in most(all?) cases does "yes" for you under the hood

Comment: what is the method to delete because I've taken a dump of the whole IDL on the type library and I can find nothing.  I don't think permissions/pivileges is an issue.  Also the popup is thrown by the Shell dll not Excel, it looks exactly like Windows Explorer dialog and not at all like an Excel dialog so `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` would sadly not help.

Comment: Confirmed that `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` does not fix.  Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: It would help to show your existing VBA code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred answer is the use the MoveHere method to move the old one out the way before adding.  That way no dialog box is thrown.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can delete a file from a zip using Shell:

```
Sub DeleteFromZip()

    Dim fldr, zpath, itm, vrbs, vrb

    zpath = "C:\_stuff\test\test.zip"

    Set fldr = CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(zpath)

    For Each itm In fldr.items
        If itm.Name = "IMG_0000322_2014.03.11.jpg" Then
            itm.invokeverb "Delete"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next itm

End Sub
```

This does raise a confirmation dialog though - see this link for how to avoid it:

[FolderItem.InvokeVerb("Delete") without confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388004/folderitem-invokeverbdelete-without-confirmation)

Comment: Yeah, I got to the answer that's in the link.  I just used MoveHere method to move the old item out the way before adding the new version.   Thanks.