# Delete files on connected android device with AHK

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I have an autohotkey script, and I need to delete a specific file on it using automation. It's connected via usb, and I can access it in the file explorer (windows) via `This PC\myS21\Phone\...\data.txt`. How can I delete this file with ahk?

I tried simply calling `FileDelete, path`, but (as I understand), this wont work because the file is not within the computers filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from UI-based solutions, the best API way is to of course use adb. And adb doesn't require root, it just needs to have adb debugging enabled in developer options.

To run the adb file delete command in AHK:

`Run, adb shell rm /sdcard/Download/data.txt`

Another way is to use the COM Interface provided by the Windows system:

```
phone := GetDeviceFolder("Phone Name")
phone.ParseName("Internal Storage\Download\data.txt").InvokeVerb("delete")

GetDeviceFolder(deviceName) {
    shell := ComObjCreate("Shell.Application")
    computer := shell.Namespace("::{20d04fe0-3aea-1069-a2d8-08002b30309d}")
    for item in computer.Items
        if item.Name = deviceName
            return item.GetFolder()
}
```

Source: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=6395#p42773

Comment: The com approach is perfect, thank you! On my machine I get a popup that asks for confirmation. Off the top of your head do you know a way to suppress that?

Comment: @Warlax56 Microsoft didn't seem to open the no confirmation option for COM. One solution is moving the file to an accessible location such as temp folder and use FileDelete to delete it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388004/folderitem-invokeverbdelete-without-confirmation

Comment: So maybe it's a better option to just confirm that dialog with ControlSend or SendInput